# ASP.NET Core Web App Dependency Injection with Multiple Implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do you register services in an enumerable way? For example I'm working on a solution similar to OpenLM. I would like to have a configuration file that defines the inputs.  For example:

```
"Collectors": {
"Frequency": "2",
"FlexLM": {
  "ExePath": "Resources\\lmutil.exe",
  "Servers": [
    {
      "Server": "port@server",
      "Product": "product"
    }
  ],
},
"SentinelRMS": {
  "ExePath": "Resources\\lsmon.exe",
  "Servers": [
    {
      "Server": "server",
      "Product": "product 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This requires two services, one knows how to communicate with FlexLM and the other with Sentinel RMS. I've implemented it a non-IoC way like this

```
internal static IEnumerable<IDataCollector> Build()
{
    var time = DateTime.Now;
    var collectors = new List<IDataCollector>();
    AddSection("Collectors:FlexLM", collectors);
    AddSection("Collectors:SentinelRMS", collectors);
    return collectors;
}

private static void AddSection(string section, List<IDataCollector> collectors)
{
   if (ConfigurationAdapter.Sections.Contains(section))
   {
        var exePath = ConfigurationAdapter.Config.GetSection($"{section}:ExePath").Get<string>();

        var children = ConfigurationAdapter.Config.GetSection(section + ":Servers").Get<ServerConfig[]>();
        if (children != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in children)
            {
               if (section == "Collectors:FlexLM")
               {
                   collectors.Add(new FlexLmDataCollector(item.Server, item.Product, exePath));
               }
               else if (section == "Collectors:SentinelRMS")
               {
                   collectors.Add(new SentinelRmsDataCollector(item.Server, item.Product, exePath));
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Later in the process these services are consumed in parallel like this

```
Parallel.ForEach(collectors, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 99 }, (collector) =>
{
    collector.ReadLicenses();
});
```

Creating a service for communicating with

Answer (score 0):

I created one service for each type of license server. Each service is responsible for multiple servers, which are passed in a `IOptions`. First I configured the services.

```
builder.Services.Configure<SentinelRmsServiceOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(SentinelRmsServiceOptions.Section));
builder.Services.Configure<FlexLmServiceOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(FlexLmServiceOptions.Section));
builder.Services.Configure<DataCollectorsOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(DataCollectorsOptions.Section));
```

Register multiple services

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataCollectorService, SentinelRmsDataService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataCollectorService, FlexLmDataService>();
```

The constructor for the service that calls the server specific services looks like this

```
public DataCollectorsService(
    ILogger<DataCollectorsService> logger,
    IEnumerable<IDataCollectorService> services,
    IOptions<DataCollectorsOptions> options)
```

The options class matches the appsettings.json

```
public class FlexLmServiceOptions
{
    public static string Section => "Collectors:FlexLM";
    public string ExePath { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ServerInfo> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

The service communicates with the servers using the original classes

```
Parallel.ForEach(options.Servers, item =>
{
    var collector = new FlexLmDataCollector(item.Server, item.Product, options.ExePath, enrichers);
    collector.ReadLicenses();
});
```